AWS step function : Error handler in lambda does not pass correct data to AWS state machine
I have state machine which uses lambdas ,s3 copy/deleteObject, pass states,choice states,...

simply what it does is to get object from "pending" folder , process it(using a lambda) and based on result, copy object to "failed" folder if any error occures
Now , the problem is : error handling part does not work correctly .when err happens, I need objectKey to pass to s3CopyObject but I get exception.
This is that part of my state machine:
  "ProcessRecords": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:XXXXX:function:recordProcessing",
      "ResultPath": "$.submissionResult",
      "Next": "SubmitToExternalAPI",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "ResultPath": "$.errorInfo",
          "Next": "Error"
        }
      ]
    },
 "Error": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "ResultPath": "$",
  "Next": "CopyObjectToFailed",
  "InputPath": "$.errorInfo"
},
"CopyObjectToFailed": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Parameters": {
    "Bucket": "processing-bucket",
    "CopySource.$": "States.Format('processing-bucket/Pending/{}', $.errorInfo.objectKey)",
    "Key.$": "States.Format('Failed/{}', $.errorInfo.objectKey)"
  },
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:copyObject",
  "Next": "FailureDeleteObjectFromPending"
},//....

and this is lambda code (typescript)for error handling part:
export async function processRecords(event: { bucket: string, objectKey: string }): Promise<ExternalSubmissionContent> {
//....
catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error processing S3 event: ${error}`);
        const errorMessage = error instanceof Error ? error.message : JSON.stringify(error);
        throw {
            errorType: "Error",
            errorMessage: `Error processing S3 event: ${errorMessage}`,
            objectKey: objectKey
        };
    }

but when error happens I get exception on step function when reach Err pass state:
An error occurred while executing the state 'CopyObjectToFailed' (entered at the event id #16). The function 'States.Format('processing-bucket/Pending/{}', $.errorInfo.objectKey)' had the following error: The JsonPath argument for the field '$.errorInfo.objectKey' could not be found in the input '{"Error":"object","Cause":"{\"errorType\":\"object\",\"errorMessage\":\"[object Object]\",\"trace\":[]}"}'

and on Error pass I have this as part of input
"errorInfo": {
    "Error": "object",
    "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"object\",\"errorMessage\":\"[object Object]\",\"trace\":[]}"
  }


A catcher returns a string payload as an output.  You'll need to convert the Cause string to JSON to select the objectKey from it using States.StringToJson
For more info see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html
